# Maven support for Resin 4

Tags: maven-3, resin

I can not get the *resin-maven-plugin* working. Actually I want to test my web app on different App Servers (Jetty, Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish all work great) by executing `resin:run`.
I tried the snapshots and final versions, but all have problems. The latest versions report:

> Cannot find setter, adder nor field in com.caucho.maven.MavenRun for
>   'contextRoot'

There is a bug report about this issue, but Caucho is not supporting this plugin anymore.

So here my questions:

1. Is there a working version available?
2. If not, where can I find the source code (and then fix it myself)

Comment: I have the same issue and I tried many times. No success until now. :(